# Invalid mouse offset for cross-frame draggable + sortable

Tags: javascript, iframe, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-droppable

We are currently trying to accomplish cross-frame dragging between draggables and sortables provided by jQuery UI. This is working properly now. However, the mouse offset seems off when dragging from the parent to the child frame--please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r5nfe/6/.

Code in the parent:

```
$('#my-frame').load(function () {
    $('.draggable').draggable({
        appendTo: 'body',
        helper: 'clone',
        iframeFix: true,
        revert: 'invalid',
        connectToSortable: $('#my-frame').contents().find('.sortable'),
        cursorAt: { top: 0, left: 0 } 
    });

    $('#my-frame').contents().find('.sortable').sortable({
        iframeFix: true,
        cursorAt: { top: 0, left: 0 } 
    });
});
```

Code in the child frame:

```
var containers = $('.sortable');
containers.sortable({
    connectWith: containers,
    cursor: 'move',
    revert: true,
    cursorAt: { top: 0, left: 0 } 
});
```

Can someone please tell us how to fix the mouse offset?

Comment: Solution refined, you can check the update at the beginning of the post

Comment: The problem probably comes from https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7925

Comment: This project solves that for droppables: https://github.com/maxazan/jquery-ui-droppable-iframe. But it doesn't work for sortables (https://github.com/maxazan/jquery-ui-droppable-iframe/issues/2) and the author doesn't seem to maintain this project. I think a solution could be similar and one would need to fix something in jQueryUi within `sortable.refreshPositions();`

Comment: There is a bounty to a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482689/jquery-ui-draggable-sortable-in-iframe-wrong-vertical-offset

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34915119/offset-issues-with-jquery-draggable-into-an-iframe-based-sortable/39998974#39998974

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **solution 2 update**

I added this js function because when you add too many draggable element to the iframe, the drag elements can be overlapped by the sortable elements if you scroll down

```
$('.draggable').on('dragstop',autoResize);


function autoResize(){
    var newheight;
    if(document.getElementById){
        newheight=document.getElementById('my-frame').contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
    }
    newheight=newheight+100;
    $('#my-frame').css('height',newheight);
}
```

here the [new jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Jwxv/42/)
**end solution 2 update**

This problem appear to be a bug and someone have made his solution ( basically a workaround): [trasparent div solution](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/drag-drop-into-iframe#14737000001672027)

**1**
My first solution, without changing the code, could be in placing the iframe before of the draggable stuff, as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KwJcs/3/), the code:

```
<iframe id="my-frame" src="/VqxGf/3/show"></iframe>
<ul>
    <li class="draggable">Drag me</li>
    <li class="draggable">Drag me 2</li>
    <li class="draggable">Drag me 3</li>
</ul>
```

**2**
Another solution that seems to work is to play with the style property: position absolute for the ul in which contain the draggable

s, a bit of margin-top for the sortable stuff in the frame and, maybe, a frameborder=0. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Jwxv/21/)
The main page:

```
<ul style="position:absolute">
    <li class="draggable">Drag me</li>
    <li class="draggable">Drag me 2</li>
    <li class="draggable">Drag me 3</li>
</ul>
<iframe frameborder="0" id="my-frame" src="/ATu6F/30/show"></iframe>
```

The iframe page:

```
<ul id="sortable" style="margin-top:100px" class="sortable idle">
    <li>Sortable</li>
    <li>Sortable 2</li>
    <li>Sortable 3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="sortable idle">
    <li>Sortable</li>
    <li>Sortable 2</li>
    <li>Sortable 3</li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps.

### ***Please see the edit at the beginning of this post***

Comment: Thanks @JoDev I would like to let you know that I updated that solution to avoid that the draggable stuf be overlapped from the sortable content when you scroll

Comment: when i run this code i get this error:  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.overflowOffset.top')

Comment: yes this code gives the error i mentioned when using jquery-ui-1.11.2

Comment: Thats a bug. See https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/15047
This project solves that for droppables: https://github.com/maxazan/jquery-ui-droppable-iframe. But it doesn't work for sortables (https://github.com/maxazan/jquery-ui-droppable-iframe/issues/2) and the author doesn't seem to maintain this project. I think a solution could be similar and one would need to fix something in jQueryUi within `sortable.refreshPositions();`

Answer (score 0):

I've tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/r5nfe/83/) for my part. But it doesn't work perfectly.

I change the `appendTo` with **parent.body**, and the `cursorAt` with **100** on top param.

```
$('#my-frame').load(function () {
$('.draggable').draggable({
    appendTo: 'parent.body',
    helper: 'clone',
    iframeFix: true,
    revert: 'invalid',
    connectToSortable: $('#my-frame').contents().find('.sortable'),
    cursorAt: { top: 100, left: 0 } 
});

$('#my-frame').contents().find('.sortable').sortable({
    iframeFix: true,
    cursorAt: { top: 0, left: 0 } 
});
});
```